# How to get all deleted data back from Oracle database? 

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-restore

I have dropped all the tables from Oracle database using  SQL Developer. All the tables are in recycle bin?  What should I do to get all the data back?

Comment: Have you enable Oracle recycle bin?[link](http://www.orafaq.com/node/968)

Answer (score 6):

You can check if your objects are in the recycle bin by querying the [`recyclebin`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4230.htm#sthref2043) view:

```
SELECT object_name, original_name, type, can_undrop, droptime FROM RECYCLEBIN
```

You can undrop a table with the [FLASHBACK TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9012.htm#SQLRF01802) statement:

```
FLASHBACK TABLE your_table TO BEFORE DROP;
```